# Need to iterate through SQL table rows, one at a time (table too big to use adapter.Fill)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, memory, row

It's easy enough for me to read through a small SQL Server 2005 table like this:

```
string cmdText = "select * from myTable";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, connection);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);
```

Unfortunately, this method appears to load the entire table into memory, which simply isn't going to work with the gigantic tables I'm working with.

I would like to be able to iterate through the table one row at a time, such that only one row needs to be in memory at once. Something along the lines of:

```
foreach (DataRow row in rowIteratorObject)
{
  // do something using the row

  // current row goes out of scope and is no longer in memory
}
```

Kind of similar to the way you can use StreamReader to deal with a text file one line at a time, instead of reading it all in at once. Does anyone know of a way to do this with table rows (or, if I'm barking up the wrong tree, an alternative solution)?

Answer (score 16):

You should use a DataReader:

```
using( var connection = new SqlConnection( "my connection string" ) ) {
    using( var command = connection.CreateCommand() ) {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM myTable";

        connection.Open();
        using( var reader = command.ExecuteReader() ) {
            var indexOfColumn1 = reader.GetOrdinal( "Column1" );
            var indexOfColumn2 = reader.GetOrdinal( "Column2" );
            var indexOfColumn3 = reader.GetOrdinal( "Column3" );

            while( reader.Read() ) {
                var value1 = reader.GetValue( indexOfColumn1 );
                var value2 = reader.GetValue( indexOfColumn2 );
                var value3 = reader.GetValue( indexOfColumn3 );

                // now, do something what you want
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you enclosed the connection with a using statement, there is no need to close it, it will be closed automatically. check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx

Comment: I know, but I used to close connection after every query. It's usefull in complex web applications, where you want use a connection-pooling for requests.

Comment: However in th this sample is "connection.Close()" actualy spare.

Answer (score 10):

Just use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I was pretty sure that there'd be a native .NET way of doing this, but it's hard to search Google for a concept. I needed a class name to get my investigation started!